# Use docker --build-arg in sed regex

Tags: linux, bash, docker, sed

As part of my Dockerfile build I am trying to use sed to replace parts of my package.json file. The following command works from the regular linux command line (on my host machine):

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN=MySecretToken && sed -i -E "s/git\+ssh:\/\/git/git\+https:\/\/${GITHUB_TOKEN}:/g" package.json
```

This works fine, and does the trick. I then try to do the same thing in the dockerfile:

```
ARG TOKEN
RUN export GITHUB_TOKEN=$TOKEN && sed -i -E "s/git\+ssh:\/\/git/git\+https:\/\/${GITHUB_TOKEN}:/g" package.json
```

Then when I build it with:
    $ docker build --build-arg TOKEN=MySecretToken .

It fails with the following error message: 
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unknown option to `s'

All help appreciated

**FINAL EDIT: Current status**
I still cant get it to work using docker on my host machine, but I tried on a GCP vm, and it actually works like it should. There might be some copy-paste related issues between my linux vm and windows machine. Sorry if that is the case, I appreciate the answers and comments I've gotten.

**Edit:**
I've gotten some concerns about the security of this method, so I'll try to clarify:

I do mean to insert this token at build-time, not at runtime. The reason is that we are using private git repos for depencencies in our package.json. To install these without setting up git in the build-container, we can use a github deploy-token. We are planning on using Google Cloud Build for our builds with this token encrypted. During the build (in the same build step) we plan to:

- make a copy of the original package.json
- decrypt the token
- use sed to replace parts of our package.json with the decrypted token
- run npm install
- replace the tampered package.json with the original package.json

This is also just parts of the first build step in a multistage build. The final image (and its docker history) will only contain the compiled application, and none of the build time dependencies (like the source code directory, package.json), and no traces of any token (neither encrypted nor decrypted).

For a blog post about a similar approach, see https://medium.com/@kevinsimper/how-we-do-docker-multi-stage-builds-and-secure-sharing-of-private-repositories-956eda84f3b8

Comment: Note that this will make the token visible to anybody who has your image and can run `docker history` on it.  You probably don't want that.

Comment: Two `sed` tricks: (1) put `echo` before the sed command to see the actual command that's being sent in after shell quoting, and if it's wrong, fix it.  (2) you can use any punctuation on the `s` command and have to escape that specific character, so _e.g._ `s@git\+ssh://git@...@g` might be easier to read.

Comment: More than likely your slash isn't being escaped enough. Either docker parsing the dockerfile or the shell inside the container, or possibly both, are parsing the backslash before it gets to the sed command.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I am aware of the security issues this method brings. For brevity I left out that it will be an encrypted key that will be decrypted in the same step, before running sed. Package.json will also be replaced with the original package.json in the same build step, meaning it the decrypted key should not be visible anywhere. Additionally it is a multistage-build, so the final image wont have the package.json or the token. I'll update my post with more info on this process.

Answer (score 1):

ARG is used when you pass parameters on build time, for example:

```
docker build -t mydocker \
    --build-arg TOKEN=MySecretToken .
```

I assume you wanna pass that token when the image starts, so you should pass the parameter as an environmental parameter, in this way you can reuse the same container but pass different token. Also inject the token in package.json in entrypoint.sh

```
docker run -d --rm --name mydoc -e GITHUB_TOKEN=MySecretToken mydocker
```

In this way, the GITHUB_TOKEN will be part of environment variables, which is good.

Of course in entrypoint.sh you can do the substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -E "s/git\+ssh:\/\/git/git\+https:\/\/${GITHUB_TOKEN}:/g" package.json
...
```

My suggestion is to not pass that token at all, I assume you plan to run npm install inside the container, and generate the node_modules in other container (cache container) and copy the node_module folder to your container. In this way you don't expose at all your token.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do however want to use this token at build time, and not on runtime as you suggest. The reason being I need to run npm install with several private git repositories. I'll update my post with more details.